# How to solve this ODE: $\ddot x = \frac{\alpha}{x^3} - \beta x$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Any pointers as how to solve the ODE, $$\ddot x = \frac{\alpha}{x^3} - \beta x$$.

Comment: Same as any ODE of the form $\ddot x=f(x)$: multiply by $\dot x$ and integrate both sides.

Comment: Tried that! Turns out to be complicated!

Comment: Then its complicated, but it's still what you need to do.

Comment: I guess so! Thought there might be some niche transformation.

Comment: There is the constant solution $$x = \sqrt[4]{\frac{\alpha}{\beta}}$$ Another thing to note is when this function is integrated, it is almost a perfect square, mod a constant. If you have initial conditions this would be the best time to plug them in.

Comment: Yes thats the minima of the potential. But unfortunately I dont have the initial conditions.

Comment: [Wolfram gives very complicated solutions](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=dsolve+%28x%27%29%5E2+%3D+k-%281%2Fx%2Bx%29%5E2) I don't think there will be an easy way to simplify that.

Comment: Exactly. I'm also stuck at integrating $\frac{1}{\sqrt{C - (x-\frac{1}{x})^2}}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the equation is autonomous, the substitution $\dot{x} = f(x)$ yields the ODE

$$f'(x) f(x) = \frac{\alpha}{x^3} - \beta x,$$

which has to be solved for $f(x)$. Note that this equation is separable, therefore, one obtains the implicit solution

$$f^2(x) = - \frac{\alpha}{x^2} - \beta x^2 + c,$$

where $c$ is a constant. Now in order to get $x = x(t)$, one has to solve the equation

$$\int  \frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{-\alpha /x^2 - \beta x^2 + c}} = \int \frac{x}{\sqrt{-\beta x^4 +cx^2 - \alpha}} \mathrm dx = \int \mathrm dt,$$

where I only look for the positive solution for $f$ and positive $x$ (other cases are treated similar). For suitable assumptions on $\alpha, \beta$ and $c$ this integral can be calculated analytically via the substitution $u = x^2$. Therefore, you obtain the implicit $1$-parameter family

$$\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\beta}} \arcsin \left(\frac{2 \beta x^2 - c}{\sqrt{c^2 - 4\alpha \beta}}\right) = t + C.$$

Comment: Just to solve as $x=f(y)$: $   x=  \sqrt{\frac{1}{2 \beta} \sqrt{c^2 - 4\alpha \beta} \sin( 2 \sqrt{\beta} t + \phi)+ \frac{c}{2 \beta} }$

Answer (score 0):

One thing I should try is to switch variables and write the equation as
$$-\frac {t''} {(t')^3}= \frac{\alpha}{x^3} - \beta x$$ Then, reduction of order would lead to
$$t'=\pm\frac{x}{\sqrt{-\alpha +c_1 x^2-\beta  x^4}}$$ which can be integrated (see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+x%2FSqrt%5Bk*x%5E2+-+%5C%5BAlpha%5D+-+x%5E4*%5C%5BBeta%5D%5D)).